# Isolation Capacitance (Cio)

Tags: capacitance, isolation, digital-isolator

How I can find a practical value of CIO barrier capacitance (primary to secondary side) in digital isolators?

Comment: Actually i want to measure it in a practical way to verify the value in the datasheet. How and which equipment i should use to measure the isolation capacitance of digital isolator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Actually i want to measure it in a practical way to verify the value
>   in the datasheet. How and which equipment i should use to measure the
>   isolation capacitance of digital isolator?*

Use an oscilloscope with known input capacitance (that is quite a common thing to know for a decent oscilloscope) and place the device under test in series with the input to the o-scope and feed an input signal to isolated port of the device and compare the AC amplitudes of input and output and get a decent measure for the attenuation: -

[image]

Use a frequency of around 1 MHz so that the scope's input capacitance dominates the input resistance (usually 1 Mohm or 10 Mohm).

Basically you are forming a potential divider and using input and output amplitudes to calculate the "unknown" device capacitance.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. But i could't get you very well. I am little confused about the oscilloscope capacitor and its configuration with my test device? I want to test insulation capacitance of driver ic at V(t)=0.4(2*pi*1M*t). Could you share some circuit or detailed about this method? I would be very thankful.

Comment: @Luqman I've added a picture. Hopefully this makes sense now.

Comment: i got it Thanks for your time and help

Comment: Could you suggest me some circuit topology and design test method which is more efficient and convenient to use in life time test for digital isolators?

Comment: *More efficient* than what? What is a *lifetime test* supposed to do? Not enough information to make any suggestions really - maybe consider asking a new question?

Comment: I think you should raise a new question because it's not directly related to how to measure the isolation capacitance (this question).

Answer (score 0):

If no spec in the datasheet, assume 1pf.

if the isolator includes an internal faraday shield, then maybe 0.1pf.

There will always be Efield coupling from input_to_output on the PCB, and between package pins.

Comment: @Andy aka Could you suggest me some circuit topology and design test method which is more efficient and convenient to use in life time test for digital isolators?